# a curious definite integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need to evaluate the following definite integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^b}{\ln x}dx\;,$$
where $b<-2$ or $b>-1$. Any insight is welcome.

Comment: Your integral does not converge.

Comment: Differentiating under the integral sign (see p. 8 [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf)) will work, but make sure all the appropriate hypotheses are satisfied. In fact, before this, make sure the improper integral actually converges.

Answer (score 1):

By a change of variables $x=e^{-t}$, 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^b}{\ln x} dx= -\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(b+1)t} dt}{t}.$$
The integrand $e^{-(b+1)t}/t$ is positive for $t>0$, hence $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(b+1)t} dt}{t} \ge \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-(b+1)t} dt}{t} \ge \max\{e^{-(b+1)},1\}\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t} = \infty.$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^b}{\ln x} dx= -\infty .$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{\quad x \equiv \expo{-t}\quad\iff\quad t = -\ln\pars{x}}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{b} \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x&
=\int_{\infty}^{0}{\expo{-bt} \over -t}\,\pars{-\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
=-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\pars{b + 1}t} \over t}\,\dd t \to -\infty
\\[1mm]&{\tt\mbox{Diverges logarithmically at the lower limit !!!}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The Laurent series of $x^b/\ln x$ at $x=1$ is $\frac{1}{x-1} + O(1).$
The integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x-1}$ diverges to $-\infty$ near $x=1$, hence $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^b}{\ln x} dx = -\infty$$